# c++ multiple level indirection with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im having trouble displaying the values in arr[0] and arr[1] when = to size. It displays instead the address. How would i fix this.

```
int checkVal (int size, int c)
{
    cout << c << ". ";
    cin >> size;
    do{if (size < 0)
    {
            cout << size << " is not a non-negative integer. Re-enter --> " << c << ". ";
        cin >> size;
    }
    }while(size < 0);

    return (size);

}

void Input (int **&x, int **arr, int size1,int size2, int a, int b)
{

    cout << "Please enter 2 non-negative integer values: "<< endl;
    checkVal(size1, a);
    checkVal(size2, b);

    putArr(x,size1,size2);

    arr[0] = size1;
    arr[1] = size2;
    cout << arr[0] << "   " << arr[1] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int size1, size2;
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    int** x;
    int*** y;
    int** q;
    int**** z;

    int *arr [2];

    allocArr(x, y, q, z);
    Input(x, arr, size1, size2, a, b);
    checkVal(size1,a);
    putArr(x, size1, size2);
    summation(y, arr);
    display(z);


}
```

And yes all the pointers are necessary for this specific program. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `int *arr[2]` creates a `array of pointers` with 2-elements. If you want an array of 2-elements you need to change it to `int arr[2]`.

Comment: You may use a single while instead of do while and if. For your problem please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

`checkVal` gets `size` by value. it doesn't change the variable sent to the function.

so it is look like `checkVal` need to get size by reference, and you don't need to return.

like this:

```
void checkVal (int &size, int c)
{
    do{
       cout << c << ". ";
       cin >> size;
       if(size < 0){
          cout << size << " is not a non-negative integer. Re-enter --> ";
       }
   }while(size < 0);
}
```

In addition: are you sure the pointers are correct? I see too much stars (*)

Comment: This code should also check whether `cin >> size` failed, otherwise it goes into an infinite loop